# Sci-fi book: a girl lives on a pink sea world and colonists arrive

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

This was a library book I read as a child, and I can't remember what it was called. It was the late 80s/early 90s? It had a pink cover, I think. Paperback. A girl is on an alien planet totally covered by sea, the sea may have been pink, or the sky was pink. Some colonist aliens arrive in a huge, towering spaceship, and touch down in the sea. They're a threat. That's all I can remember. Can anyone help?

Comment: That's pretty scant on details, but maybe Arthur C. Clarke's *Songs of Distant Earth*? Published in 1986.

Comment: I know, sorry, it is scant on details. Thanks for your reply. It wasn't Songs of Distant Earth. I think it was a female writer.

Comment: Not a pink cover but possibly Reefsong by Carol Severance? Or a Door into Ocean by Joan Slonczewski?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think it might have been one of those two. The memory of a pink cover bamboozles me.